# How to Group Items By Common Path Dynamically Behind Code?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

My C# WPF application dynamically populates the listView1 with 100s of 1000s of files in the given directory in this manner:

```
File Name | Path | Size
ABC.docx | C:\Mike | 30 KB
OPQ.rar | E:\Tims \ 10 MB
CDE.jpg | D:\Jobs | 15 KB
XYZ.png | C:\Mike | 10 KB
GHI.tmp | D:\Jobs | 2 KB
```

I want to dynamically group all files together by their common Paths.

This is what I tried-

```
public class filesList
{
   public string File {get;set;}
   public string Path {get;set;}
   public long Size {get;set;}
}

CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView1.ItemsSource);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Path");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

Expected Output-

```
File Name | Path | Size
Group1:
ABC.docx | C:\Mike | 30 KB
XYZ.png | C:\Mike | 10 KB

Group2:
CDE.jpg | D:\Jobs | 15 KB
GHI.tmp | D:\Jobs | 2 KB

Group3:
OPQ.rar | E:\Tims \ 10 MB
```

Comment: I don't think anything's wrong with your grouping code. Could be the way you're updating the UI? Can you check the contents of the original ItemsSource against the results of your CollectionView by debugging?

Comment: Works for me too, how are you assigning your ItemsSource?

Comment: Hi Tyressand and @MarkFeldman, thank you both of you for the replies. Unfortunately, I'm still struggling as a beginner in WPF.
 
Here's my error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

It shows the property "view" is "null" in this line: view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

Comment: Hi @Tyress, I don't know how to use ItemsSource bcz I'm populating listView items from a Data Table. All examples on the Internet I went through spoke about populating List Arrays into ItemSource.

Comment: Finally, I fixed it! Since I was populating items from a Data Table, I was missing this line: listView1.ItemsSource = dataTable1.DefaultView

Comment: @JohnJM good that you fixed it!